# What is this two-player card game?

Tags: identify-this-game

[image]

Per the mockup above...

What is this game called? It's been in my family since I was a kid and I never could find it on the web. Here are the rules:

- It's two player
- Each player gets five cards in their hand
- Player one's cards are objective-0, discard-0, discard-1, discard-2, discard-3, and discard-4.
- Player two's cards are objective-1, discard-9, discard-8, discard-7, discard-6, and discard-5
- The objective of the game is to remove cards from your own objective pile (12 cards each) by playing them into the four play areas (play-0, play-1, play-2, and play-3).
- You can only play into the central areas by sequential rank. Ace being first, then two, then three, all the way to king. Once the king is played, that pile get's shuffled back into the deck-0.
- If you can't play anything you discard one of our cards from your hand into the discard piles to end your turn.
- [EDIT] The game is played with two decks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems quite similar to [Spite and Malice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spite_and_Malice), though that has four discard piles per player rather than five, and is typically played with multiple decks of cards (perhaps requiring more than four play piles).